# Can't commit changes after computer crashed

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

When I worked in unity3d, my computer crashed and reloaded. And now I can't commit file of the scene. I can't delete it, because it is important file. How can I fix this? Only with **reset hard**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove que file index.lock and try again